# Custom button not appearing on iOS device

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

So I'm trying to implement a custom button in my iOS app to replace the default rounded rectangle button. Heres a code snippet:

```
UIImage *normalImage  = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Images/whitebutton.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
UIImage *pressedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Images/bluebutton.png"]  stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12.0 topCapHeight:0.0];

[self.theButton setBackgroundImage:normalImage  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.theButton setBackgroundImage:pressedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

When I run it in the simulator everything works fine, my custom button shows up. However, when I run it on my actual device the button just appears as the default one with no customisation at all. Anybody got any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add whitebutton.png and bluebutton.png to your project. And call `imageNamed:@"filename"` not `imageNamed:@"file path"` . Also , when running on the simulator there is no problem with case sensitivity. On the device , you have to type the correct name of the file because it IS case sensitive.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

George

Comment: Ahh brilliant. Removed the file path and works a treat now! many thanks

Comment: If you found the answer useful , please mark it as correct so others will know what was the solution for your question. It is also a good practice here on Stack Overflow  , people will answer your question faster if you have a decent acception rate. Glad you solved it. Cheers!

Comment: Done. I'm new around here so just getting my bearings! thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The iOS file system is case sensitive, unlike the sinulator's. I'd start by checking that "Images" directory.

(Quick test if I'm barking up the wrong tree: does the `+imageNamed:` call return nil?)

Answer (score 0):

Your resources are going to get flattened in your app bundle. Also, the filesystem on iOS is case sensitive while the filesystem on Mac OS X is case preserving, so make sure the actual filenames of your images are case-correct. If they are, just remove the `Images/` prefix and it should work:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluebutton"];
```

Also, if the image is a png type, you don't need to specify the file extension with `imageNamed:`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"whitebutton.png"]
```

and

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluebutton.png"]
```

Regardless of how you have it visually organized in Xcode, it all gets flattened in the bundle